# Jquery failing to insert working div in html with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my problem:

I am trying to make a game and insert a div that lets you go into a different room after you have completed part of the game. My problem is that the div gets inserted with the correct class however, it doesn't seem to allow me to go into the room but if I put the div in the HTML, then I can go in.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapperID" class="wrapper">
...
<div id="hud">Inventory:
    <ul>
       ...
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- This is where the div is supposed to be -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thirdWrapper {
   background-image: url("../images/city4-2.gif");
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: green;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: contain;
}
.room-1 {
   background-image: url("../images/room-1.jpg");
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: green;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: contain;
 }
#doorEntry {
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 28.5%;
    top:40%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Javascript(jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
...
$("#item3").click(function() {
    if(document.getElementById('item3').getAttribute("src") == "images/hammer.png"){
        $("#wrapperID").toggleClass("thirdWrapper");
        $("#wrapperID").toggleClass("secondWrapper");
        var door = document.createElement("div");
        door.className += "doorEntry";
        door.setAttribute("id", "doorEntry");
        var element = document.getElementById("wrapperID");
        element.appendChild(door);
    }
});
$("#doorEntry").click(function() {
    $("#wrapperID").toggleClass("room-1");
    $("#wrapperID").toggleClass("thirdWrapper");
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call $("#doorEntry").click(...) after appending the div to the html:

```
$("#item3").click(function() {
    if(document.getElementById('item3').getAttribute("src") == "images/hammer.png"){
        $("#wrapperID").toggleClass("thirdWrapper");
        $("#wrapperID").toggleClass("secondWrapper");
        var door = document.createElement("div");
        door.className += "doorEntry";
        door.setAttribute("id", "doorEntry");
        var element = document.getElementById("wrapperID");
        element.appendChild(door);
        $("#doorEntry").click(function() {
            $("#wrapperID").toggleClass("room-1");
            $("#wrapperID").toggleClass("thirdWrapper");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The main problem is actually that `$("#doorEntry")` doesn’t contain any elements outside the `#item3` click handler because that element isn’t in the DOM. If you’re _within_ the function, however, you can also replace `$("#doorEntry")` by `door`, because that variable refers to the newly created `div`. There’s no need to search the `div` in the document again. With this replacement, the event listener could also be assigned at _any_ point after `var door = …`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#doorEntry").click(function() {
```

should be

```
$(document).on('click', "#doorEntry", function() {
```

You are inserting the div by hand. So it does not have attached to it the event because attaching the event happened on load. So you need to catch the click like this or after you insert the element attach the click event to it.